# How to send email automatically in Yii2?

Tags: yii2, swiftmailer

How to send email automatically?

My current scenario is I want to trigger mail sending automatically after 15 days.

Comment: Please format your question correctly; and where you can provide examples of what you have tried.

Comment: You need to write a cron job for that

Answer (score 2):

First step would be to **create a command line** that can be called to send the mail.
Yii2 supports commands. I would recommend you to make a simple command like this (place in /command app dir). You will need to update config/console.php if using db etc

```
namespace app\commands;

use yii\console\Controller;


class mailController extends Controller {

    public function actionSend() {
       //code here to send the mail
    } 
}
```

The code sample to send mail can be obtained [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-swiftmailer-mailer.html)

Now you can run this command from shell / command prompt in the yii root dir as below

```
yii mail/send
```

Next step is to **run this command every 15 days**.

Running scheduled jobs require you to have an external trigger on your set interval.
On unix systems, this trigger is provided by cron jobs , an example [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/204265/how-to-configure-cron-job-to-run-every-2-days-at-11pm)
You can configure the cron job as below

```
0    0    1,16  *   *   /path/to/yiiroot/yii mail/send
```

Comment: I guess it should be `php yii`?

Comment: Not necessary, yii has its own command line binary /batch script (which actually does call php), php yii can be used too though.

Comment: this has to be run from the dir where yii is placed. and use `./yii mail/send` , or alternatively you can use the full path to the file from anywhere  `/path/to/yii/yii mail/send` , eg if I have my app in /var/www/yiiapp, this would be `/var/www/yiiapp/yii mail/send`